# Cannot use managed event/objects in unmanaged code error c3265, c2811

Tags: c++-cli

Native C++ library that I am using in C++/CLI project raises events giving me results,

- If I try to handle the event by extending the unmanaged event, it says the ref class can only extend ref class.
- I then tried to create a native event but have manged object inside it to collect the results, but I get the error cannot declare managed object in unmanaged class.

Is there anyway to get it done in one of the ways I am trying, or should I declare unmanaged result objects fill them in unmanaged event and then Marshall it ?

**Edit:**

```
class MyNativeListener: public NativeEventListener
{ 
private:
    ManagedResultsObject ^_results;
public:

void onEndProcessing(ProcessingEvent *event) 
{
    _results.Value = event->value;
      //Many more properties to capture

}

};
```

This is what I am trying, I have extended the native event listener to capture the event, but not sure how to capture the results to a managed object.

**Edit2**
Found this while searching on the same line as suggested by @mcdave [auto_gcroot](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/07/12/Mixing-Native-and-Managed-Types-in-C_2B002B00_.aspx)

Comment: The notion of a 'native event with a manged object inside it' is pretty mysterious.  Post code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your native class needs to store a handle to the managed object instead of a reference to it. You can do this using the [gcroot template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(v=VS.100).aspx). If you dig into the gcroot template you will find it uses the [GCHandle Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx), which with appropriate static casting can be stored as a `void*` pointer and so provides a means of storing managed references in native code.

Try expanding your code along the following lines:

```
#include <vcclr.h>

class MyNativeListener: public NativeEventListener
{ 
private:
    gcroot<ManagedResultsObject^> _results;
public:
    void onEndProcessing(ProcessingEvent *event) 
    {
        _results->Value = event->value;
        //Many more properties to capture
    }
};
```