# pin_ptr cannot declare a managed object in an unmanaged class

Tags: c#, c++-cli, interop

I have unmanaged class. In that class I have a managed object. Now I want a pin_ptr for the managed object in my unmanged class. And when I try to do this I get this error "error C3265: cannot declare a managed _`pinnedProject` in an unmanaged `ProjectWrapper` How can I achieve this?

Here is the code.

```
class ProjectWrapper
{
private:
    msclr::auto_gcroot<Project^> _project; // --> This works fine,
    pin_ptr<msclr::auto_gcroot<Project^>> _pinnedProject; // ---> This gives error
public:
    ProjectWrapper()
    {
        _project = gcnew Project();
        pin_ptr<msclr::auto_gcroot<Project^>> anotherPinnedProject = &_project; // --> This one works,
        //_pinnedProject = _project; // --> I want to use this instead of above live,
    }
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB removed tag. Was added by mistake, Project^ is c# class. ProjectWrapper is c++,

Comment: May this link help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025967/cannot-use-managed-event-objects-in-unmanaged-code-error-c3265-c2811) have you included all needed header files

Answer (score 6):

The MSDN article about `pin_ptr<>` is not shy about telling you why this cannot work:

> Pinning pointers can only be declared as non-static local variables on the stack.
>
> Pinning pointers cannot be used as:
>
> - function parameters
> - the return type of a function
> - a member of a class
> - the target type of a cast.

Which is all for a rather good reason, this kind of object pinning is *very* efficient.  It doesn't require an explicit call into the CLR at all, the pin is discovered when the garbage collector walks the stack looking for roots.  That requires the object reference to be a local variable, the compiler emits it in the MSIL with the [pinned] attribute.  Also exposed in the C# language with the *fixed* keyword.

So, no can do, nor should you pursue this.  Pinning an object for a long time is very detrimental to GC, it is a rock in the road and prevents heap segments from getting recycled.  You should only pin at the exact moment in time that you need the pointer to be stable, that moment only occurs inside of the code of the function that uses the pointer.

If you want to wish this problem away then you need to fall back to the heavy pin.  That requires [GCHandle::Alloc()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1246yz8f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), passing GCHandleType::Pinned.  You get the pointer you need from AddrOfPinnedObject(), release with the Free() method.

Comment: Actually my _project (Managed) object loses its information when constructor is completed. So I cannot use _project in other methods. It gaves me null exception as GC has collected the object. So I need to find a method through which I make sure GC doesn't collect it. I was able toe find that pin_ptr is the key,

Comment: Also this line "pin_ptr<msclr::auto_gcroot<Project^>> anotherPinnedProject = &_project;" works inside constructor. Why I cant make this as a class member?

Comment: You need to read the quoted MSDN text again.  It doesn't work in the constructor either, the object is only pinned as long as the constructor code is running, it will not be pinned after that.  Storing the pointer is a very gross bug that will make your code randomly fail.  Using GCHandle::Alloc() like I recommended also ensures that the object cannot be collected.

Comment: I will try using that. Will let you know about the results, thanks,