# How to add a managed value type member to an unmanaged class?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am trying to create a native C++ class called `MyNativeClass` that can be used by non-managed code. The member functions of `MyNativeClass` are implemented using managed code. In addition, the managed code needs a `System::Numerics::BigInteger` object, but when I attempt to add a `System::Numerics::BigInteger bi_` field to `MyNativeClass`, I get

> error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'bi_' in an unmanaged 'MyNativeClass'

Here is a simplified code listing which demonstrates what I am trying to achieve:

`mynativeclass.h`

```
class MyNativeClass
{
    //...

public:
    MyNativeClass();
    //...

private:
    System::Numerics::BigInteger bi_;

    //...
};
```

`mynativeclass.cc`

```
MyNativeClass::MyNativeClass()
    : bi_(BigInteger::Zero)
{
    //...
}
```

I am not sure why this is not allowed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use managed event/objects in unmanaged code error c3265, c2811](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025967/cannot-use-managed-event-objects-in-unmanaged-code-error-c3265-c2811)

Comment: The subject of mixing types is complex, and requires you study the subject before proceeding. However, to get you started, gcroot<String^> str would let you put a String^ in a native class, via gcroot. That should lead you to the solution

Comment: @user1937198: I saw that other question, but I think that this is different.  In the other question, it seems that `ManagedResultsObject` may be a reference type, or the question-asker wanted to have the additional level of indirection.  In my case, I would like to have the value type within the native class directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have managed data inside native types.  The reason is that objects of native types are outside the purview of the garbage collector, and wouldn't keep managed objects from dying.

"I know that", you say.  "But value types aren't kept on the managed heap and don't need to have their lifetime tracked by the garbage collector!"  Quite true.  But managed value types may contain handles to reference types.  If the garbage collector can't see them, it can't keep their referents alive (or adjust them when the generational garbage collector compacts the heap / promotes objects to a higher generation).

It would be possible for blittable data (that doesn't contain handles) to be stored directly inside native memory.  And in fact this is allowed for primitive types, which have dual identify (native `int` == `System.Int32`, for example).  But it's not allowed for any composite types, presumably to keep the language rules simple.  And `BitInteger` wouldn't be allowed anyway, because it does need to keep a handle to a variable-sized content area (using dotPeek or the reference source, it is revealed to be a `array<unsigned>^`) in order to support arbitrary precision.

The workaround is to use the `GCHandle` feature of the garbage collector, to keep objects alive from outside the garbage collector's realm.  But replacing all handles inside a value class with GCHandles would result in an incompatible in-memory layout, so it wouldn't actually be the same type anymore.  Simplest solution is to use `gcroot<>` (which is a nice C++/CLI interface to `GCHandle`) to a reference class type, and stick your managed value types inside that.

The C++/CLI team originally tried to allow hybrid types, but things got complicated and ended up with the separation rules you see now.  There was a rather nice blog article about that but I can't find it now.

Comment: Incompatible in-memory layout with *what*? He's defining the class, there's nothing else for it to be incompatible with.

Comment: @Puppy: He's not defining the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` type.  The framework one has a `uint[]` aka `array<unsigned>^` inside, a native equivalent would have to have a `gcroot<array<unsigned>^>` in its place.

Comment: True... but he also isn't affecting it, so why would that matter?

Comment: What I mean is, since BigInteger is a *value* type, the memory layout seems neither here nor there, as there will be nobody accessing it by a pointer or reference and expecting one layout and receiving another.

Comment: @Puppy: Because the garbage collector could yank out [the array of bits](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,41) associated with that `BigInteger`, leaving a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Puppy: All member functions (methods) of `BigInteger` receive a pointer to the instance.  That's how [the .NET calling convention for value types works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Seems to me like that can be solved by another layer of indirection, no? Generate some completely random CLR class with a BigInteger as a member, forward the functions on, and use a gcroot to that.

Comment: @Puppy: That's exactly what I said: "Simplest solution is to use gcroot<> (which is a nice C++/CLI interface to GCHandle) to a reference class type, and stick your managed value types inside that."  It doesn't, however, qualify as "have the value type within the native class directly" which Daniel requested.